# How can I echo a statement from a form?

Tags: php, html

I'm a student doing a challenge where I would have to make a Calculator-type form where you can input two values and click an operation. It's a simple concept using only 4 operations.

I was able to make the format of the form: title, input text and buttons. But I can't find a way to take the input information and manipulating the information. My initial goal was to take the two values and adding/subtracting/multiplying/dividing the values and printing the statement above.

For example:

1 + 2 = 3 //statement printed above

First Value:   `1`   
Second Value:   `2`    //insert values

`+` `-` `*` `/` //click operation buttons

Any suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<?php
  print_r($_POST);
  if ( isset($_POST["+"]) ) {
    $sum = $var1 + $var2;
    echo "$var1 + $var2 = $sum";
  }
  elseif( isset($_POST["-"]) ) {
    $sum = $var1 - $var2;
    echo "$var1 - $var2 = $sum";
  }
  elseif ( isset($_POST["*"]) ) {
    $sum = $var1 * $var2;
    echo "$var1 * $var2 = $sum";
  }
  elseif ( isset($_POST["/"]) ) {
    $sum = $var1 / $var2;
    echo "$var1 / $var2 = $sum";
  }
?>

<html>
   <body>
     <form action="" method="POST">
      First Value: <input type="text" name="First Value"><br><br>
      Second Value: <input type="text" name="Second Value"><br><br>
      Operations: <button type="submit" name "+">+</button>
                  <button type="submit" name "-">-</button>
                  <button type="submit" name "*">*</button>
                  <button type="submit" name "/">/</button>
     </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add relevant textual information as text, rather than images. Unlike images, text can be copied and searched.

Comment: Take a look at the [formatting help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) if you're unsure how to achieve it.

Comment: I re-edit the question because I figured out how to add the code in text form instead of inserting a picture. I hope this gives more context.

Comment: If this is your entire code, you're using uninitialized variables (`$var1` and `$var2`). Those should be values you got from your inputs. As for echoing, you can add a `div` element just above or below the form and print the operation there. You don't have to `echo` in the same place where you do your calculation.

Comment: Its a **TYPO Explosion**. Look at a basic HTML tutorial then a How to FORMS tutorial

Comment: First **missing = sign** in `name="+"` and the other symbols

Comment: Second, **incorrect name** used in input. change `name="First Value"` to `name="var1"`

Comment: Third, **How to address variables in the POST array** `$sum = $_POST['var1'] + $_POST['var2'];`

Comment: Fourth, **How to output array variables in a string** `echo "$_POST[var1] + $_POST[var2] = $sum";`

Comment: Fifth, **move all HTML output inside the** `<html><body>` tags

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly, that really helps! I'll try that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to fix the errors I mentioned in comments

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
  
  if ( isset($_POST["+"]) ) {
    $sum = $_POST['var1'] + $_POST['var2'];
    echo "$_POST[var1] + $_POST[var2] = $sum";
  }
  elseif( isset($_POST["-"]) ) {
    $sum = $_POST['var1'] - $_POST['var2'];
    echo "$_POST[var1] - $_POST[var2] = $sum";
  }
  elseif ( isset($_POST["*"]) ) {
     $sum = $_POST['var1'] * $_POST['var2'];
    echo "$_POST[var1] * $_POST[var2] = $sum";

  }
  elseif ( isset($_POST["/"]) ) {
    $sum = $_POST['var1'] / $_POST['var2'];
    echo "$_POST[var1] / $_POST[var2] = $sum";

  }
}
?>

     <form action="" method="POST">
      First Value: <input type="text" name="var1"><br><br>
      Second Value: <input type="text" name="var2"><br><br>
      Operations: <button type="submit" name="+">+</button>
                  <button type="submit" name="-">-</button>
                  <button type="submit" name="*">*</button>
                  <button type="submit" name="/">/</button>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the right way to do things but you can use jquery in the script section to do so, let's say you have this form

```
<form id="target" action="destination.html">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

so on the submit you do the math

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  //do the math//
  document.write(//your answer//);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: As the question was tagged with HTML and PHP I would guess the OP will be learning Javascript after getting the basics of PHP

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$first_num = $_POST['first_num'];
$second_num = $_POST['second_num'];
$operator = $_POST['operator'];
$result = '';
if (is_numeric($first_num) && is_numeric($second_num)) {
    switch ($operator) {
        case "Add":
           $result = $first_num + $second_num;
            break;
        case "Subtract":
           $result = $first_num - $second_num;
            break;
        case "Multiply":
            $result = $first_num * $second_num;
            break;
        case "Divide":
            $result = $first_num / $second_num;
    }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page-wrap">
    <h1>Simple Calculator Program</h1>
      <form action="" method="post" id="quiz-form">
            <p>
                <label>First Number</label>
                <input type="number" name="first_num" id="first_num" required="required" value="<?php echo $first_num; ?>" /> 
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Second Number</label>
                <input type="number" name="second_num" id="second_num" required="required" value="<?php echo $second_num; ?>" /> 
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Result</label>
                <input readonly="readonly" name="result" value="<?php echo $result; ?>"> 
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Add" />
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Subtract" />
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Multiply" />
            <input type="submit" name="operator" value="Divide" />
      </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not accepted, you need to explain your answer with some words!